# Python error when injecting XML content into tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Trying to build xml and inject a string with many elements. However by doing following getting error and not sure what is wrong.

```
from lxml import etree
from lxml.builder import E as e

list = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]

fields = "".join("<field>{}</field>".format(x) for x in list)

xml = page = (
e.req(
  e.tab(
    e.fields(
      etree.fromstring(fields)
    )
  )
)
)
```

error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Extra content at the end of the document, line 1, column 20
```

python (2.7.10)
lxml (3.7.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML files [must have a single top-level root element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element), but you're trying to parse from a list of `<field>`s (line breaks added for readability):

```xml
<field>one</field>
<field>two</field>
<field>three</field>
<field>four</field>
<field>five</field>
```

If you wrap those in a root element it should work:

```xml
<fields>
  <field>one</field>
  <field>two</field>
  <field>three</field>
  <field>four</field>
  <field>five</field>
</fields>
```